Model Binding of dictionary in .NET 8 Minimal API
When someone calls my api endpoint (Minimal API), I would like to pull a dictionary from the query string.
I have the following query parameter struct for my Minimal API endpoint (simplified for this example):
public struct QueryParameters
{
    [FromQuery]
    public Dictionary<string, string>? Filters { get; init; }
}

If I don't use the [FromQuery] attribute, I see this error:
Parameter           | Source                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Filters             | Body (Inferred)
queryParameters     | As Parameter (Attribute)


Did you mean to register the "Body (Inferred)" parameter(s) as a Service or apply the [FromServices] or [FromBody] attribute?


My endpoint is defined like (simplified for this example):
public async ValueTask<IResult> GetAllAsync([AsParameters] QueryParameters queryParameters)
{
    return TypedResults.Ok();
}

When I try to start my Minimal API, dotnet throws the following error:

Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Filters must have a valid TryParse method to support converting from a string. No public static bool Dictionary<string, string>.TryParse(string, out Dictionary<string, string>) method found for Filters.

Looking at a few resources, I have the impression that potentially there's no out-of-the-box model binding for dictionaries in net8 Minimal APIs.
I have tried adding a an extension method to Dictionary<string, string> for the TryParse, but couldn't get that path to work (kept seeing the same error).
How do I solve this problem?

You can get the values from the request directly, probably it would be the easiest option. For example:
public struct QueryParameters
{
    public HttpRequest Request { get; set; }
    
public Dictionary<string, string?> Filters => Request.Query.ToDictionary(q => q.Key, q => q.Value.ToString());
}

Or just inject the HttpRequest as a parameter of handler function.
If you want you can wrap it into some binder:
public struct QueryParameters
{
    public DictionaryBinder Filter { get; init; }
}

public struct DictionaryBinder
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Values { get; private set; }

    public static ValueTask<DictionaryBinder> BindAsync(HttpContext context) =>
        ValueTask.FromResult(new DictionaryBinder
        {
            Values = context.Request
                .Query
                .ToDictionary(q => q.Key, q => q.Value.ToString())
        });
}

And then use queryParameters.Filter.Values.

I appreciate the answer, though - I'm sorry - I don't believe this answers my question. I am not looking to turn my query parameters into a dictionary, I am looking to parse a dictionary from one of the query parameters (like here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#dictionaries).

@DavidPoxon sorry, misunderstood the question. Will try to look tomorrow.

Based on my research , the issue is that not possible to bind complex objects from query string values using [FromQuery] attribute in minimal APIs referred from MinimalAPI - Did you mean to register the "Body (Inferred)" parameter(s) as a Service or apply the [FromService] or [FromBody] attribute? .
And in my test Post with  FromBody does work.
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapPost("/api/get-all", async ([FromBody] QueryParameters queryParameters) =>
{
    return await GetAllAsync(queryParameters);
});

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

static async ValueTask<IResult> GetAllAsync([AsParameters] QueryParameters queryParameters)
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    return TypedResults.Ok(queryParameters.Filters);
}

struct QueryParameters
{
    public Dictionary<string, string>? Filters { get; init; }
}

static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static bool TryParse(string input, out Dictionary<string, string> result)
    {
        result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // Custom parsing the input into a dictionary
        try
        {
            var pairs = input.Split('&');
            foreach (var pair in pairs)
            {
                var keyValue = pair.Split('=');
                if (keyValue.Length == 2)
                {
                    result[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

Custom Model Binder still cannot bypass the body infer issue.
